# Obtaining the "default" mockup TinyMCE configuration on Plone 5

Tags: tinymce, plone, plone-5.x

I'm trying to configure TinyMCE inside Plone 5 template (so: not the z3c.form widget type).

Using the [TinyMCE Mockup patter](http://plone.github.io/mockup/dev/#pattern/tinymce) you quickly learn how to display a rudimentary TinyMCE configuration (without any i18n support).
But how I can get the "default" configuration applied to TinyMCE when it's loaded for default content types like a Plone page?

What I'm looking for a way to get the right value for the `data-pat-tinymce` HTML attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're asking for is to do something like this...

First, get the default tinymce pattern configuration:

```
from zope.component import getMultiAdapter
import json
pattern_options = getMultiAdapter(
  (context, request, None),
  name="plone_settings").tinymce()['data-pat-tinymce']
tiny_options = json.loads(pattern_options)
```

Then, manipulate the `tiny_options` dictionary and customize to your needs and provide it to your data-pat-tinymce attribute with json.dumps.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from @vangheem answer I found also an alternative way using [mimetype select pattern](http://plone.github.io/mockup/dev/#pattern/textareamimetypeselector).

You must configure the pattern with a JSON like this:

```
conf = {"textareaName": "text",
        "widget": {"text/html": {"pattern": "tinymce",
                                 "patternOptions": tiny_options}}}
```

...where `tiny_options` is the one taken from the accepted answer above and `textareaName` is the HTML textarea name where you want to activate TinyMCE.